# Is it permutations or combinations to find the number of ways 36 characters can be arranged in a 4-letter sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If I have a number in base $36$ (a to z, 0 to 9), and I want to see how many ways those characters can be arranged in a $4$-digit number, what is that called? Is it a permutation or a combination? Would I do $4^{36}$ or $36^4$?

Comment: 1) Is repetition of digits allowed (as you put it, I think it should)? 2) Usually, we don't call $0=0000$ a four-digit number; does your problem agree with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

$$
1000_{36} \leq k \leq (35)(35)(35)(35)_{36}
$$
$$
36^3 \leq k \leq 36^4 - 1
$$
the total number of ways
 $= 36^4 -1 - 36^3 + 1$

So the answer is 
$$
36^4 - 36^3
$$

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, if the order doesn't matter, it's a combination.
If it does matter, it's a permutation.

$1HI_{36}$ ( which is 1296 in decimal) is different from $HI1_{36}$ (which is 3781 in decimal)

So it would be a permutation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Permutations.

**Combinations**:
$$
   \frac{n!}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}
$$

**Permutations**:
$$
    \frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!}
$$

As you can see, Combinations remove any duplicate meaning arrangements since they're seen as the 'same thing'

Comment: That's not what the question asks. It asks how many numbers have four digits when written in base $36$. So repetition is allowed. Also, permutations should have factorial in the denominator.